# What ASCII codes could potentially be rendered as blank spaces in text?

Tags: java, ascii

Suppose I have a utility function like this -

```
public static boolean isABlankSpace(char c)
  {

     // returns true if the char c is rendered as a blank space
  }
```

My current implementation only does-

```
if(c == ' ') 
 {
    return true;
 }
```

But I realize that many other ASCII codes could be rendered as blanks. So which are these ASCII codes? And how would that change my implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
Character.isWhitespace(c);
```

which is a built in utility method. Details of what it does is in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29). Note that it will return true for line breaks (`\n`, `\r` etc.) too.

Comment: +1 there are many more than you might expect. A quick program find 27 code: `9
10
11
12
13
28
29
30
31
32
5760
6158
8192
8193
8194
8195
8196
8197
8198
8200
8201
8202
8203
8232
8233
8287`

Comment: I have saying that Character.isWhiteSpace might give you *more* than you expect. Some white space are not actually blank. Some characters which are not spaces have no width in many fonts (making them invisible) It depends on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i will add 2 more:

tab \t

and

the zero width space:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Answer (score 0):

```
Character.isSpaceChar(c);
```

This returns true if the character is any of the following:

```
SPACE_SEPARATOR
LINE_SEPARATOR
PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR
```

[Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29)

To avoid other characters being interpreted as space chars, you can cast to ASCII:

```
int j = (int) c;
if(j == 32) return true;
```

But of course consider unicode builds.